# How to set session value input in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a form filter vuejs :

```
       <b-row>
          <b-col md="3">
            <b-form-group>
              <label>Name:</label>
              <b-form-input
                placeholder="Name"
                type="text"
                class="d-inline-block"
                v-model="name"
                v-on:change="changeFilter()"
              />
            </b-form-group>
          </b-col>
          <b-col md="3">
            <label>Gender:</label>
            <v-select
              :options="genderOptions"
              class="w-100"
              v-model="gender"
              v-on:change="changeFilter()"
            />
          </b-col>
      </b-row>
```

I have a `methods` get value input and select :

```
methods: {
    changeFilter() {
      console.log(this.name, this.gender)
    },
  },
```

Now I want to reload the page but on input or select still show the value I selected. Help me please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the first good practice is not to have cangeFilter() like this on click but changeFilter. So If I understand you correctly, you want to reload the page and still have the same value selected for this. You can save the value in the local storage assume that it's not sensitive data.

[local storage info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
Save data in local storage

```
localStorage.setItem('gender', 'Male');
```

Getting the data (you will need to use a lifecycle hook-like mounted to initialize the data)

```
mounted() {
   this.gender = localStorage.getItem('gender') || 'what ever default you have';
}


<b-form-input
            placeholder="Name"
            type="text"
            class="d-inline-block"
            v-model="gender"
            v-on:change="changeFilter"
            :value="gender"
          />
```

[the value in HTML input form](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp)

Comment: Thanks bro. I did as you instructed, but when I reload the page.. it still loses the value displayed on the input ?

Comment: did you ser the item when you click on input (@onChange)

Comment: and make sure you have the value property to initialize the value

Comment: I do that `localStorage.setItem('gender', this.gender);`.. but when I refresh the page, it still has no value in the input.. I don't know where did I go wrong? Can you write more clearly for me..Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you add the mounted lifecycle?

Comment: I did that..Input is set..but select shows value, not lable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234594/discussion-between-json-and-shaked).